# Make my java application shut down if it stops working

Tags: java

Is there a way to make my java application shut down there is an error? e.g. if I have a nullpointerexception, can I just make it completely close out?

Comment: Catch it and invoke System.exit(1)?

Answer (score 3):

Any uncaught exception at the top level will automatically halt the thread it's in. If you have more than one thread in your program, the other threads will still survive. If you want to terminate explicitly, you can call `System.exit()`

Comment: An uncaught exception will halt that *thread*, but won't "automatically kill your program" if you have more than one thread.

Comment: @GregKopff or propagate it to the caller, if it is thrown from inside a method :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `System.exit(0);` to terminate the JVM.

However, you should avoid `NullPointerException` by checking the reference before using it:

```
if(foo != null) foo.doSomething();
```

Comment: The advice *"you should"* should read *"you could"*.  Blindly making a change like this could actually make the real problem worse / harder to find.

Comment: Note that it is conventional to exit with a non-zero code (such as System.exit(1) ) to indicate that the exit is the result of some problem, not the virtual machine reaching the end of the program without incident.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, catching the exception and calling `System.exit()` is (generally) the right approach.  But there is more to it than that:

Q: Do I really need to catch it?

A: If your application is a conventional command-line application, and the exception is thrown on the "main" thread, then you may not need to catch it.  Uncaught exceptions on the main thread will cause the application to exit ... if there are no other non-daemon threads in existence.  (In fact, the same thing goes for **any** thread ... )

However if your thread has more than one non-daemon thread, then you need to do something to stop the application.  Like catch the exception and call `exit()`.

Q: Where do you catch it?

A: On the stack of any thread where the "fatal" exception might be thrown.  There are two ways to do this:

- Put a try / catch (Throwable) in the `main(String[])` method, a thread's `run()` method, etcetera.
- Install a default uncaught exception handler.

What you DON'T want to do is to add `System.exit()` calls all through your codebase.  That approach leads to all sorts of problems with reusability, unit testing and generally figuring out "why has the *effing* application died again".

Q: What if it is already caught?

A: One reason why your application might not be exiting naturally, is that your code is already catching the exception ... by accident.  For instance:

```
    try {
       doSomething()
    } catch (Exception ex) {
       handle an IO exception
    }
```

In the above, some ignorant / lazy programmer hasn't bothered to consider the exceptions that might be thrown in `doSomething` and has assumed that they are all some kind of IO related exception.  But if the exception was actually an unexpected `NullPointerException` ... or something worse ... then the code has just squashed it.

The cure for this kind of thing is code-reviews and mentoring to cure the programmer of his bad habits ... hopefully before he does too much damage to the codebase!  And if you find this kind of thing in your codebase, you should fix it immediately ... and probably "grep" for similar occurrences and fix them too.